# SPA w/ Node.JS and Express and .ejs

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

How would you show parsed data on a single page app. For instance, I am able to console.log the quotes generated from the API, but I'm not sure how to post them on the single page.

Index.ejs:

```
<% include ./partials/header %> 
<div class=container>
    <h1>Free2BGeek</h1>
    <h3>This is your joke for the day!</h3>
    <hr>
    <p>
        "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse sit amet turpis ex. Vivamus aliquet ipsum tortor, at rhoncus ligula efficitur condimentum. Sed pretium arcu quis ex fringilla, et consectetur odio sodales."
    </p>
</div>
<% include ./partials/footer %>
```

app.js

```
const express        = require("express"),
      app            = express(),
      request        = require("request"),
      bodyParser     = require("body-parser"),
      mongoose       = require("mongoose");

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/geek-jokes", { useNewUrlParser: true });
mongoose.set('useFindAndModify', false);
app.set("view engine", "ejs");
app.use(express.static("public"));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));

app.get("/", function(req, res){
    res.render("index");
});

let options = {
    url: 'https://geek-jokes.sameerkumar.website/api',
    method: 'GET'
};
request(options, (err, response, body) => {
    if(!err && response.statusCode == 200)
        var parsedData = JSON.parse(body);
        console.log(parsedData);
});

app.get("*", function(req, res){
    res.send("Error - I'm sorry, the page you tried to get to either does not exist or has been removed.");
});
app.listen(process.env.PORT, process.env.IP, function(){
    console.log("Geeks are ready!");
});
```

I want to be able to replace the Lorem Ipsum text with the joke.

My current results look like:

[Index Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qX2y6.png)

I tried to put

```
<p>
   <%= options %>
</p>
```

But I only get an error. Should I be using a POST route to replace the ext with? OR is there another way to embed the quote from the api?

===========================================================================

Thank you both to ***THEWOLF*** and ***Lawrence Cherone***. The code was updated in the **app.js** file and is as follows:

```
const express        = require("express"),
      app            = express(),
      request        = require("request"),
      bodyParser     = require("body-parser"),
      mongoose       = require("mongoose");

var url = process.env.DATABASEURL || "mongodb://localhost:27017/geek-jokes";
mongoose.connect(url);

mongoose.set('useFindAndModify', false);

app.set("view engine", "ejs");

app.use(express.static("public"));

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));

app.get("/", function(req, res){
        let options = {
            url: 'https://geek-jokes.sameerkumar.website/api',
            method: 'GET'
    };

    request(options, (err, response, body) => {
        if(!err && response.statusCode == 200)
            var parsedData = JSON.parse(body);
            console.log(parsedData);
            res.render("index", {body: parsedData });
    });
});

app.get("*", function(req, res){
    res.send("Error - I'm sorry, the page you tried to get to either does not exist or has been removed.");
});

app.listen(process.env.PORT, process.env.IP, function(){
    console.log("Geeks are ready!");
});
```

Comment: You would need to call the api first then pass the result the view `res.render("index", {joke: parsedData });` (presuming parsedData is the joke string) then in the view access joke, RTM: https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-template-engines.html

Comment: Thank you very much. I made it `<%= body %>` in the HTM, put the let and request inside the get request and wrote `res.render("index", {body: parsedData });` in the request function. I honestly second guessed myself...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to pass the data object you want to send to front end like this

```
app.get("/", function(req, res){
    res.render("index",{data:'your data like this in here'}); // change like this and acess it in front end the way you have done it 
});

let options = {
    url: 'https://geek-jokes.sameerkumar.website/api',
    method: 'GET'
};
request(options, (err, response, body) => {
    if(!err && response.statusCode == 200)
        var parsedData = JSON.parse(body);
        console.log(parsedData);
});
```

Comment: if you are happy with this answer please vote it as the correct one

Comment: Thank you very much for your help as well.